# "Your requirement could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

The problem is when I tried to create a new app it kept showing lists of problems and did not create the application properly. When I use artisan serve nothing happens

[image: image of the error message]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the lack of the `fileinfo` extension.

In new versions of PHP, this extension is bundled with installation, but on Windows devices, you must enable this extension inside your `php.ini` configuration file.

Open the file `php.ini` file in the directory (C:\Program Files\php-8.3.4\php.ini) and look for the line that looks like this:

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

Remove the semicolon so that it becomes like this:

```
extension=fileinfo
```

And that's it, everything should start working normally. In case you get other error messages about missing extensions, just look for them inside your `php.ini` file and uncomment them, for example, if you get an error message about a missing `pdo_sqlite` extension then open the `php.ini` file and remove the comment to enable it:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

---

**Note for future readers:** You can get the path of the `php.ini` file being used by running the command `php --ini` in your terminal, it will tell you the exact location of the file. Here's an example:

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d
```

Comment: @Wanhaikal You're more than welcome!